# android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar icon alignment issue

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-toolbar, android-appcompat, android-actionbar-compat

Using the new Android 5.0 Toolbar approach, and following the Google IO example, I'm setting a navigation icon and a spinner in the toolbar.

The issue is, the navigation icon is BOTTOM-aligned.  I can't find any reason why this is happening...

[Note that I deliberately set it to a solid square to see the alignment issue more clearly]

[image]

My code is as follows:

toolbar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:theme="@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ActionBarPopupThemeOverlay"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
    />
```

Main Style

```
<style name="ActionBarThemeOverlay" parent="">
    <item name="android:background">@color/appMainColor</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#fff</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#ffff</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#3fff</item>
</style>
```

ActivityMain

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

if (mActionBarToolbar != null)
    mActionBarToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try to use *?attr/actionBarSize* instead of *android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"*

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">
```

Comment: That was the fix!!!  The widget is now centered vertically!  Grazie Gabriele!  So I take it this is because "android:" doesn't apply to support classes?

Comment: Can you explain the use of `?attr`?

Comment: What if your specifying this programmatically?

Comment: I would give you a hug if I could.

Comment: Weird that applications like the play store have a fixed height toolbar making their icon alignment all wrong. Good thing the internet still knows how to build a decent app!