# Set NavigationDrawer's ListView margin programmatically

Tags: android, android-listview, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

I am currently struggling to design my application the way i want to.
In my app i am using a NavigationDrawer and different fragments. By clicking on an item in the NavigationDrawer i swap out the fragment that is currently active.
There is one main fragment which shows a map and doesn't show a toolbar. When I switch to another fragment I want to show my toolbar and let the user interact with it.
Now when I show the toolbar I have to set the top margin of the NavigationDrawer to the size of the toolbar so it doesn't get overlapped.

When I am showing the toolbar I set the margin of the NavigationDrawer's listview like this:

```
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) mDrawerListView.getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins(0, drawerMarginTop, 0, 0);
mDrawerListView.setLayoutParams(params);
mDrawerListView.requestLayout();
```

The outcome is like the complete opposite of what i expect. It seems like the margin is applied to the bottom of the view.

Screenshot:

[image: Listview margin not correctly set]

Another thing that annoys me is that the toggle-arrow of the toolbar is not centered correctly. It's a little bit higher than it should be, so it overlaps the system bar in the top and doesn't fill the whole size of the toolbar. I tried to make this clear in the following picture:

[image]

If you need any xml or code just let me know and I will edit my question.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT 1+2:

My toolbar style:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/my_color"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

EDIT 3:

The Problem with the toggle-arrow not being centered is fixed now. Thanks to Alchete.

Unfortunately the NavigationDrawer is still buggy. I found out that if I open and close the NavigationDrawer many times it somehow changes its layout at one time and the margin is set correctly... Is there any way to force this top happen immediately?

After many times of opening and closing the drawer it looks like this: (Exactly what I want it to look like)

[image]

There must be a way to force this immediately, right?

Answer (score 1):

Your alignment issue is most likely due to your toolbar height.  You should be setting the toolbar height as follows:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">
```

Here's the same issue for reference:  [android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar icon alignment issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446870/android-support-v7-widget-toolbar-icon-alignment-issue)

I would also be using Google's IOSched app for reference on how to set these items up properly.  You can find all the code on Github.

Here are their layout files.  Scroll down to see their toolbar/navdrawer layouts:  https://github.com/google/iosched/tree/dfaf8b83ad1b3e7c8d1af0b08d59caf4223e0b95/android/src/main/res/layout

And, also note that Google's reference design is to OVERLAP the toolbar with the navdrawer -- which is not how you have it.  And, the right margin should be equivalent to the toolbar height.

See here:  http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

[image]

Comment: I already have this in my toolbar. I edited my question and added my toolbar xml. I will have a look at the google sources. But I explicitly dont want to overlap the toolbar. I know other apps where they do this. At least with an action bar.

Comment: You have the height set to "wrap_content".  Try it as shown.

Comment: I previously had "minheight=?attr/actionBarSize" so that should have worked I guess. I changed it now to "android:layout_height=?attr/actionbarSize". Still the same outcome. I edited my question with the new xml of the toolbar.

Comment: Just a general note, "android:" doesn't apply to support classes, and was the cause of the problem in the question I linked.  So be careful of it's usage, it will cause problems like the one you're seeing.  I would remove your minHeight field altogether.

Comment: Yeah I've seen that and left it out now. I found out that if I open and close the navigation drawer by clicking the toggle-button the layout will behave properly after many times of opening and closing it...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% about this but it looks like you're setting the ViewGroup layout params to be of type MarginLayoutParams. Instead, set the margin on a 'normal' root ViewGroup type e.g. RelativeLayout and pass that to the View:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
params.setMargins(0, drawerMarginTop, 0, 0);
mDrawerListView.setLayoutParams(params);
mDrawerListView.requestLayout();
```

You may want to change MATCH_PARENT to WRAP_CONTENT depending on your xml.

Comment: I used to do this. I set the margin of the navigation drawer layout and it worked. BUT the problem was that when I changed the margin of the navigation drawer the fragment were resizing. So when I swapped from a fragment with the toolbar back to a fragment without the toolbar the fragment was resizing and it didn't look very nice.